# how to add the plus button to the right side of the table view in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to add the plus button to right side of the table view to add the content of the that cell in other view.

how to add the plus button in the right side of the table view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to the iPhone [Interface Guidelines Page](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/SystemProvided/SystemProvided.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH15-SW2).
2. Under "Standard Buttons for Use in Table Rows and Other User Interface Elements" Copy the ContactAdd button(I save it as ContactAdd.png here). Add it to your project.
3. In the cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method add:

   ```
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ContactAdd.png"];



   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   //You can also Use:
   //UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];

   CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

   //match the button's size with the image size
   button.frame = frame;

   [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   // set the button's target to this table view controller so you can open the next view
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourFunctionToNextView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

   cell.accessoryView = button;
   ```

Comment: *NOTE:
Instead of copying and adding, you can also use: [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd]; instead of UIButtonTypeCustom.

Comment: the tricky part with doing either of these is passing parameters to yourFunctionToNextView: in order to know which row was pressed.
this can be done easily with button.tag=row;
but if you have sections in your table a single int isn't good enough. You need to pass indexPath. I've found this method here to do such a thing. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500327/subclass-uibutton-to-add-a-property

Comment: Yes passing the parameter is the tricky part. Your link is almost complete except it doesn't tell you how to pass the property that you add to the UIButton class. Just to complete that thought, the parameter is passed only if you include the ":" after "yourFunctionToNextView:" in the selector. So the above example would be extended with button.property=indexPath. Then, the definition of the selector would be: -(void)yourFunctionToNextView:(UIButton*)sender {}. Then within this method, you can use something like NSIndexPath *indexPath = sender.property; where property is the indexPath.

Comment: Downvoted because it's an awful hack. See below answer on how to do this properly.

Answer (score 27):

If you have a navigation bar you should add a UIBarButtonItem like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]      
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
    target:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift

```
let addButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .Add,
                                     target: self,
                                     action: #selector(yourFunction))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
```