# Subclass UIButton to add a property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I'd like to subclass `UIButton` to add some properties that i need (not methods... only properties).

Here the code of my subclass:

```
//.h-----------------------
@interface MyButton : UIButton{
    MyPropertyType *property;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) MyPropertyType *property;
@end

//.m--------------------------
@implementation MyButton
@synthesize property;

@end
```

And here how I use the class:

```
MyButton *btn = ((MytButton *)[MyButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]);
btn.property = SomeDataForTheProperty;
```

From where i obtain this error :

```
 -[UIRoundedRectButton setProperty:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x593e920
```

Thus, from `ButtonWithType` i obtain a `UIRoundedRectButton` and `(Mybutton *)` can't cast it...
What i have to do to obtain a `MyButton` object ? is `-init` the unique solution ?

Thank you!

Comment: I can confirm that with init method it works, but i obtain a UIButtonTypeCustom ... not a roundRect

Comment: subclassing the button is working for me in iOS6 and iOS7, I wonder if this was broken in earlier OS'es.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try using a category with [Associative References](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective-c_runtime?language=objc) instead. It is much cleaner and will work on all instances of `UIButton`.

UIButton+Property.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIButton(Property)

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *property;

@end
```

UIButton+Property.m

```
#import "UIButton+Property.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIButton(Property)

static char UIB_PROPERTY_KEY;

@dynamic property;

-(void)setProperty:(NSObject *)property
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY, property, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(NSObject*)property
{
    return (NSObject*)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY);
}

@end
```

//Example usage

```
#import "UIButton+Property.h"

...

UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button1.property = @"HELLO";
NSLog(@"Property %@", button1.property);
button1.property = nil;
NSLog(@"Property %@", button1.property);
```

Comment: I used `NSObject` but the type can be any type you define including `MyPropertyType` also `UIButton(Property)` is really generic consider renaming property to something more useful.

Comment: This's a clean way to do exactly  what i'm asking for :) thank you

Comment: I didn't use your answer, but I learned something new (objc_setAssociatedObject).  So thank you.

Comment: excellent - this works great for using UIButtonTypeContactAdd at the end of a row and passing objects. (when .tag isn't sufficient).

Comment: where did you initialize static char UIB_PROPERTY_KEY;?

Comment: You do not need to initialize it, the address is the key.

Comment: all we care is that it's different. Also can we combine this with sub classing for truly elegant solution.

Comment: Looks like this thing won't work with subclassing isn't it. For all IOS know the object is of type UIButton and unless you add the category to the class, which would defeat the purpose of encapsulating, it'll still complain.

Comment: This solution worked great for me, originally I was going to subclass,  but this method is soo much cleaner. Cheers!!!

Comment: I dont really think this is a clean solution... This is a hacky solution instead.

Comment: @JoãoNunes Care to explain what is ["hacky"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hack_(computer_science)#In_computer_science) about a [well documented solution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW1)?

Comment: using objc low-level methods is not pretty at all and looks hacky, subclassing is much more objective programming and less confusing.

Comment: In the case of UIButton I think this is a much better solution than subclassing, as calling buttonWithType: on a subclass will not return an object with the inherited methods.

Comment: ofc... you have to subclass the initialiser too! To create a different object otherwise you are just creating a UIButton.

Comment: Is it allowed - Would an App get approved using this?

Comment: For future users:  dont miss #import <objc/runtime.h> to avoid getting into this trouble http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025593/ios-objective-c-how-can-i-resolve-this-error-implicit-declaration-of-functi

Answer (score 12):

You need to do:

```
MyButton *btn = [[MyButton alloc] init];
```

To create your button. The `buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` only creates UIButton objects.

=== edit ===

If you wish to use a RoundedRect button; then I would suggest the following. Basically, we just create a UIView with whatever properties we want and add the desired button to that view.

---

## .h

```
@interface MyButton : UIView
{
    int property;
}

@property int property;
@end
```

---

## .m

```
@implementation MyButton
@synthesize property;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)_frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:_frame];
    if (self)
    {
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.frame = self.bounds;
        [self addSubview:btn];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

---

## Usage:

```
MyButton *btn = [[MyButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];
btn.property = 42;

[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

---

Comment: Doesn't this method limit you to using buttons of type UIButtonTypeCustom?

Comment: Now he has no access to any button methods unless he exposes btn through a property.

Comment: @Joe: okay, it could be promoted to a property, too. Or you could hide some of the `UIButton` functionality. Great Facade, Wex.

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple scheme that only involves a few library methods, no boilerplate, and just 3 lines of code for each property you want to add. There are two example properties added below: startPoint and tileState. For illustrative purposes here are the lines you'd need to add for a property like tileState:

```
//@property (assign, nonatomic) SCZTileState tileState; // tileState line 1 
//@property (assign, nonatomic) SCZTileState tileState; // tileState line 2 
//@dynamic tileState;                                   // tileState line 3
```

There's more details in my [blog post describing how this works](http://blog.stcredzero.com/post/41340175703/subclassing-a-uibutton-or-how-not-to-but-still-win)

UIButton+SCZButton.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIButton (SCZButton)
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) id assocData;
@end
```

UIButton+SCZButton.m

```
//  UIButton+SCZButton.m
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Ooghamist LLC. All rights reserved.

#import "UIButton+SCZButton.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIButton (SCZButton)
- (id)assocData {
    id data = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, "SCZButtonData");
    return data;
}
- (void)setAssocData:(id)data {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, "SCZButtonData", data,  
                             OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
@end
```

OOGTotallyTile.h

```
//  UIButton+OOGTotallyTile.m
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Ooghamist LLC. All rights reserved.
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIButton+SCZButton.h"
#define kPointLabelTag 837459

typedef enum {
    SCZTileStatePlaced,
    SCZTileStateDropping,
    SCZTileStateDropped
} SCZTileState;

@interface SCZButtonData : NSObject
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGPoint startPoint;
@property (assign, nonatomic) SCZTileState tileState;   // tileState line 1
@end

@interface UIButton (OOGTotallyTile)
@property (readonly, nonatomic) SCZButtonData *buttonData;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGPoint startPoint;
@property (assign, nonatomic) SCZTileState tileState;  // tileState line 2
@end
```

OOGTotallyTile.m

```
//  UIButton+OOGTotallyTile.m
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Ooghamist LLC. All rights reserved.

#import "OOGTotallyTile.h"

@implementation SCZButtonData
@end

@implementation UIButton (OOGTotallyTile)
@dynamic startPoint;
@dynamic tileState; // tileState line 3

- (SCZButtonData*)buttonData {
    if ( ! self.assocData) {
        self.assocData = [[SCZButtonData alloc] init];
    }
    return self.assocData;
}
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    id forwardingTarget = [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];
    if ( ! forwardingTarget) {
        return [self buttonData];
    }
    return forwardingTarget;
}
@end
```