# How to store a string value in button(cannot use tags.)

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I am creating a button. I need to store a string value in the button. I am not supposed to use tag in this case. But when, I am tapping the button I need the data stored in the button. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you need to store data in the button? Buttons should reflect state (highlighted, enabled, image and title properties are all available to reflect this) and send messages back to the controller to change state. If you could give a little more information about what you are actually trying to do, rather than how you think you should achieve it, you may get some more useful advice.

Comment: I used the settitle property in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could subclass the button class to add a new public property that stores the data you need. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500327/subclass-uibutton-to-add-a-property), too.

Comment: Isn't there any other ways I could do it.

Comment: No. But in the most cases, its better to use the "tag" property instead of custom string properties. Within a good designed code you should be able to access all data you need by the id stored in your tag property.

Comment: Would love to do what you have suggested. But I am doing patch working on someone else' code and I have limitations in creating a new file.

Answer (score 2):

When you are tapping the button, send a sender .  like

```
-(IBAction)whenTapping:(id)sender{
 sender.text; //you needed.
}
```