# Add NSString category extension to UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, uibutton

I would like to extend `UIButton` with an `NSString` for some meta info. How could I do this?

I am starting with this:

```
@interface UIButton (neoUtils)

+ (UIButton *)neoName:(NSString *)buttonName;  

@end
```

and the .m

```
#import "UIButton+NAME.h"

@implementation UIButton (neoUtils)

+ (UIButton *)neoName:(NSString *)buttonName {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton neoName:buttonName];
    NSLog(@"%@",button);
    return button;
}

@end
```

Is this on the right path? And if so - how would I possibly use it?

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate, but it's been answered before in a different context. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414718/subclassing-nsnumber.

Comment: That seems to be what I am looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that

```
@interface UIButton (neoUtils)
```

is declared in UIButton+NAME.h.

First of all, looks like that program will enter a recursive loop as soon as you call that method:

```
+ (UIButton *)neoName:(NSString *)buttonName {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton neoName:buttonName]; // <- this one
    NSLog(@"%@",button);
    return button;
}
```

because it will recurevely call the method itself.

Anyway, considering the extended object has to have a state (the NSString for the meta info has to be "remembered") I don't believe it's possible to fulfill the requirement with a category, that just extends the behaviour of the class. Then your solution didn't start on the right step I guess.

Instead I vould just create a class like

```
@interface XYMetaInfoButton : UIButton

@proerty (nonatomic, [strong|retain]) NSString *name;

@end
```

That you can then import globally in the project to have the new UIButton with meta-info.
But that's just a possibility, maybe someone has a better solution.