# How to change the each buttons background color in UIButton in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, uibutton

I have created the buttons using the loop and setting the properties and synthesize the buttons. Now i want to change the button color in the another view controller. I am setting the tag values for each button and i can get the tag values properly in another view controller, when select the buttons. Now i want to change the background color of each buttons.

Here it's sample code,

In CustomView.h

```
    UIButton *customBtn;
    property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *customBtn;
    @synthesize customBtn;
```

In CustomView.m

```
for (int i=0; i<=[resultArray count]; i++)
{
     customBtn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     customBtn = CGRectMake(X, 30, 20, 20); notsupport = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 30, 290, 20)];
     [customBtn addTarget:customDelegate actionselector(MyAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [self.view addSubview:customBtn];
     X = X + 30;

}
```

In View controller:

```
            viewController.customBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

It does affects all the buttons background color, so how can i change the background color of each buttons. If i am creating seperate instance for all the buttons and i can change the background color for the buttons. Using single instance of the buttons, how can we change the color of the button background.

Please Help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500327/subclass-uibutton-to-add-a-property

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i<=[resultArray count]; i++)
{
    customBtn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    customBtn = CGRectMake(X, 30, 20, 20); notsupport = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 30, 290, 20)];
    [customBtn addTarget:customDelegate actionselector(MyAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:customBtn];
    X = X + 30;
    customBtn.tag = i;

   [buttonAry addObject:customBtn];



}
```

By End of the loop you will have n number of buttons in `buttonAry` and each button will have unique tag.

You can read that array in another class

```
 for (int i=0; i<=[buttonAry count]; i++)
{
   UIButton *button = [buttonAry objectAtIndex:i];

   UIColor *color =  [colorAry objectAtIndex:i];


  button.backgroundColor = [UIColor color];


}
```

In `colorAry` you can have different colors

Answer (score 0):

Use the `viewWithTag` method. e.g.

`UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[viewController.view viewWithTag:aTag];`

Answer (score 0):

Either you can do with `viewWithTag`.

Or, you can create an array of `IBOutlets`, then your work will be done.

Answer (score 0):

Either follow Anoop Vaidya, or use NSNotification to send your button object to another class, it'll hold all properties of your button.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<=[resultArray count]; i++)
{
   customBtn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   customBtn = CGRectMake(X, 30, 20, 20); notsupport = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 30, 290, 20)];
  [customBtn addTarget:customDelegate actionselector(MyAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  customBtn.tag = i;

  [self.view addSubview:customBtn];
  X = X + 30;

}

-(IBAction)MyAction:(id)sender{

  UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

  NSLog:(@"tag:%d"btn.tag);
  // here you find your specific button, 
}
```