# How to store auxiliary information inside a UIButton, via Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I am building a custom keyboard, in which there are about 50 `UIButton` keys. I'd like to put some *grouping* information for each key, e.g., numbers, alphabets, cursors, etc.

The first thing comes to mind is by mean of the `tag` field (100 for alphabets, 200 for numbers, ... etc.)

Another option is by means of [a category with Associative References](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5500525/88597).

However, both methods are not very *Interface Builder-friendly*. Any other option?

Comment: I've used the buttons `title` property a lot to encode grouping information. If you want the title to be displayed on the button, simply hook up the buttons to an `IBOutletCollection`, and loop through each of the titles to get the relevant display and grouping information, and parse the string accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote

> I'd like to put some grouping information for each key, e.g., numbers, alphabets, cursors, etc.

Why not use `IBOutletCollection`s?

You can declare arrays for each of "numbers, alphabets, cursors":

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *numberButtons;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *letterButtons;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cursorButtons;
```

and easily hook them up in interface builder:

[image]

Comment: It is indeed, if you want to have a third party object which manages the buttons. However it's not quite a good solution if you want the button itself to know about its type/state (which is an OO principle btw -> encapsulation).

Comment: @ValentinRadu The button doesn't operate on that level of abstraction. It cares about images, titles, targets, and actions. Whether it's a numeric button, or a square root button, or what have you, is really a concern of the controller layer, and forcing the button to take responsibility for that is moving controller logic into the view.

Comment: @CarlVeazey the state or kind of a button is not "controller logic". But this question was never about good design, so let's agree to disagree.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the cleanest way to do it *and* handle everything in the same subclass/category is by using `User Defined Runtime Attributes`

[image]

For the example above, you should have at least one method:

```
-(void) setLocalizedKey:(NSString *) key;
//(NSString *) localizedKey; this is optional
```

or property:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * localizedKey;
```

declared and implemented(or `@synthesize`) in your `UIButton` subclass or category if you fancy associative references (or you don't need storage or don't have access to the class itself).

In the example above, the value of `key` will be `HOW_IT_WORKS` for that specific instance. This is the way I usually handle localisation, but should serve your purpose too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question but the `tag` property is definitely settable for `UIButtons` through XCode/Interface Builder.

[image]

Comment: It's my fault of not clarifying what _friendly_ means. `tag` is definitely settable in IB but it's only a number. I am looking for some intuitive alternatives. For example, what about `color`?