# Associative references with NSInteger

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ app and I'm creating a Category for an `UIButton`:

```
@interface UIButton (NotificationBall)

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger type;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger index;

@end
```

And its implementation:

```
#import "UIButton+NotificationBall.h"

@implementation UIButton (NotificationBall)

@dynamic type;
@dynamic index;

@end
```

Searching on internet I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500327/subclass-uibutton-to-add-a-property), but I haven't found any examples with `NSInteger`.

**Do I need to use NSNumber instead of NSInteger?**
**If I use, NSNumber, what do I have to do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only Objective-C objects can be set as 
associated objects, scalars cannot be used directly.
So you could declare the property as

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *type;
```

and directly use the code from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5500525/1187415
that you referenced to.

Or you keep the `NSInteger` property, and wrap/unwrap it to `NSNumber`
in the getter/setter method like this:

```
-(void)setType:(NSInteger)type
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_TYPE_KEY, @(type), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(NSInteger)type
{
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_TYPE_KEY) integerValue];
}
```

*Remark:* "type" and "index" are quite common names. You should consider prepending the property names with some prefix, to
avoid a possible name collision with existing properties of `UIButton`.