# Automatic view id's like in android

Tags: ios, view, uniqueidentifier

I need to write some gui for IOS, yet i am so used to the automatic view id's that android has, that i am at a loss when it comes to identifying views without putting explicit tags in the interface builder

is there some way to automatically identify iOS views from interface builder or otherwise ?

maybe a library that does that ?

Comment: Create your own custom property here is a link that you can refer:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500327/subclass-uibutton-to-add-a-property

Comment: not exactly what  i mean, the same way i dont need a category, i can set the tag programmatically -> i am looking for something that will do that AUTOMATICALLY

Comment: I am not asking you to create category for that i am just asking you to create custom property for your view in a class where you need.

Comment: Can id be just objective C id of object (id - pointer)

Answer (score 1):

Thats why you have IBOutlets. Create an IBOutlet for your views, like so `IBOutlet UIView *view1;` etc etc then in link the IBOutlet to your view in Interface Builder. Now you can progammatically use the `view1` variable which will modify your view associated to that IBOutlet in interface builder\

**UPDATE**

Progammatically create all your views like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    //set your x and y coordinates with some awesome maths, maybe you want to create a grid, so update the x coordinate accordingly
    UIView *view = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(whateverframe)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGesture];

    [singleTapGesture release]; //remove line if you have an ARC project

    view.tag = i; //this is just for you since you like to handle your views with id tags
}
```

Then your one method that will handle the taps for all your code

```
- (void) viewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
     UIView *viewTapped = recognizer.view; // This is the view associated with gesture recognizer.
    int id = viewTapped.tag; //heres the tag id do whatever you like

    //do something with either that view variable which will return the view that was tapped
    //maybe you wanted to change the color of it or something or change the contents of it

    //or you can do something with the id tag of that view.

    //or maybe you just want to handle it with if else statements like so
    //if(viewTapped.tag == 1) //do this
    //elseif(viewTapped.tag == 2) // etc etc
}
```

Comment: not exactly what i want-> i have a screen with 20 clickable views on it, i want to have 1 method that governs the clicks on that screen, not 20, so i need to differentiate between the given views, and except for putting tags and defining constants for those tags, i don't see any other solution

Comment: @LenaBru Check the updated code. Sure, then you can do all this progammatically then instead. One method to handle all the taps for your UIViews.

Answer (score 0):

Set Tag for each and every view using property  `setTag` and retrieve the corresponding view using `– viewWithTag:`. `[abaseView subViews]` returns an array of subviews. Filter the subviews using `Class` and `Tag`.

Comment: viewWithTag can be very costly, as it traverses the entire view hierarchy for the desired view on every call