# how to get Buttonimage name

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I've created one button like this:

```
close=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    close.frame=CGRectMake(285, 0, 35, 50);
    [self.view addSubview:close];
    [close setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close2.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [close addTarget:self action:@selector(aclose:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

and I have one NSString. When I click on the button, I need to pass the image name to NSString. Is that possible?

Comment: try this i think it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/5500525/2518805 @ios start

Comment: Yes to solve this you should make a custom class of UIButton, make a property in this custom class named imgName and use this class in place of UIButton

Comment: UIImage does not store the name of the image it contains, you can't. You have to store the name elsewhere by yourself in relationship to the Button or image.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get image name from a button as UIImage does not store the name of the image it contains. You have to store image name elsewhere by yourself. Method of storing image name depends on what you want to accomplish with the name of the image.