# IOS & Objective C - how can i resolve this error "implicit declaration of function "class_getname " is invalid in c99"?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode6

Actually there are two errors, the first one is :
"implicit declaration of function "class_getname " is invalid in c99"

The second one is : 
incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'const char*' with an expression of type 'int'

my method is :

```
-(void) donneesrecoltees:(NSData *)donnees {
    NSError *erreur;
    NSNumber *lastMessage,*currentMessage;


    //int i;
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *msg;

    UIAlertView *alert;

    NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:donnees options:0 error:&erreur];
    // Check if it's the right class to avoid error stack

    // this is the line that is causing the error
    const char* className = class_getName([json class]);

    NSString *myClass=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",className];

....

}
```

Any help on how to fix this? thank you

Comment: did you import <objc/runtime.h>?

Comment: i definetly forgot to import it, thank you very much, it resolved the error that i had.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to `#import <objc/runtime.h>`

Comment: thank you , it fixed the error, you wouldn't know why or what is the relation between this import and the error that i had by any chance  ?

Comment: The imported file defines the function.

Comment: @samouray The relationship with the error is that (a) because it couldn't find a declaration of this function, it was going to implicitly declare the function `class_getName`; but (b) this implicit declaration assumed `class_getName` was going to return an `int`, whereas your code assumed that it was going to return `const char *`. Clearly, the implicit declaration was incorrect, but if you do the `import` correctly, that incorrect implicit declaration goes away.

Comment: @rob thank you very much sir, I appreciate your precious explanations ^^