# transition from map annotation callout

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton, mkmapview

How can I go about making a view transition from when a map annotation rightCalloutVccessoryView is pressed?

Right now, that button triggers a segue for me (I added a target to the button), but I need that segue to happen with some special properties that the annotation carries.

I tried subclassing the button to hold the properties that I need, but that didnt work 100% right. Also, Ive tried using this category, https://github.com/woxtu/UIButton-WithObject, but it has a bug. I've tried associated objects, as per this solution, [Subclass UIButton to add a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500327/subclass-uibutton-to-add-a-property), but it works the same as the subclass does.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any segue linked to the button, nor any categories.

You can implement `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` of the `MKMapViewDelegate`. You can then programmatically perform the segue between the two scenes and have `prepareForSegue` pass the necessary information, or you can manually instantiate the next scene (calling the storyboard's `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`), set the properties you want, and then push/present that view controller.

Comment: Im using a library for my callout called https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview, and it doesn't currently allow for this delegate feature :((

Comment: I wound up doing some stuff with globals that fixed this